# How to add an encryption algorithm in the FreeBSD Kernel?

Tags: encryption, kernel, freebsd

I am trying to add my own cipher to the FreeBSD kernel. I searched online but couldn't really find help. I am wondering which files should i modify to link my new cipher and where to put my source code. Thanks

Comment: Cryptography is _extremely difficult_.  Do not create your own cipher.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/18197/911

Comment: I am a cryptographer, so writing my own cipher is not the hard part. The cipher is already implemented, i just want to put it in the kernel. Thanks

Comment: What do you want your cipher to do and why do you need it in the kernel ? I.E. what do you encrypt/decrypt ?

Comment: I will use it to encrypt ipsec traffic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `crypto(9)`. Most of the algorithms are found in `/usr/src/sys/crypto/`. Some algorithms and the cryptograhic framework code are in `/usr/src/sys/opencrypto/`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at sys/opencrypto/, in particular sys/opencrypto/xform.c, to see how various algorithms are integrated with the rest of the kernel.